# broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED

Tags: android, notifications, activity-manager

I noticed in Android Monitor the ActivityManager force stopping my application.  On certain devices, this happens almost immediately of removing from MRL for tasks.
I then run **adb shell dumpsys package** and noticed that indeed my process has stopped.
Now when a notification comes in I get this verbiage: "broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED..." for my process.
This is really annoying and I have attempted to find a viable solution to this and have not come up with any.
If anybody has any ideas of what I can do either avoid the OS from force killing or how to handle when this does happen I'd appreciate it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem has to do with the fact that my application was running a debug build.  If you run a release build, you will not run into this problem.  It's nice to debug so I'm not sure why Google does this.